# How to execute Request objects manually in scrappy?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to dowload a HTML only website using scrapy. I am using the CrawlSpider class to achieve this. Here's how my parser looks like. My crawler downloads the HTML source of the pages and makes a local mirror of the website. It mirrors the website successfully, but without images. To download the images attached to each page, I tried adding:

```
def parse_link(self, response):
        # Download the source of the page

        # CODE HERE

        # Now search for images

        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        imgs = x.select('//img/@src').extract()

        # Download images

        for i in imgs:
            r = Request(urljoin(response.url, i), callback=self.parse_link)
            # execute the request here
```

In the examples in [Scrapy's Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) , the parser seems to return the Request object which then get's executed.

Is there a way to execute the Request by hand, so as to get a Response? I need to execute multiple requests per parse_link call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could download images with the [Images](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html) pipeline.  Or if you want to execute the Requests manually, use `yield`:

```
def parse_link(self, response):
    """Download the source of the page"""

    # CODE HERE

    item = my_loader.load_item()

    # Now search for images

    imgs = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//img/@src').extract()

    # Download images

    path = '/local/path/to/where/i/want/the/images/'
    item['path'] = path

    for i in imgs:
        image_src = i[0]
        item['images'].append(image_src)
        yield Request(urljoin(response.url, image_src),
                callback=self.parse_images,
                meta=dict(path=path))

    yield item

def parse_images(self, response):
    """Save images to disk"""

    path = response.meta.get('path')

    n = get_the_filename(response.url)
    f = open(path + n, 'wb')
    f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: The more interesting question is how to execute all callbacks using `parse_images` before yielding an item?